# Append date to the filename using find and exec comand

Tags: linux, bash, exec

having the following bash code on Linux, how I can modify it to append the datestamp after gz accomplished his process?

```
DOMINIO=filenetvers 
DATAORA_ATTUALI=$(date +"%Y.%m.%d") 
GGZIP=1 
GGRM=90 
find /work/pr-${DOMINIO}-0[0-2]/servers -name "*.log*[^gz]" -type f -user bea -mtime +${GGZIP} -exec /usr/bin/gzip -9 -f {} "*.gz.$DATAORA_ATTUALI" \; 
find /work/pr-${DOMINIO}-0[0-2]/servers -name "*.stdout*[^gz]" -type f -user bea -mtime +${GGZIP} -exec /usr/bin/gzip -9 -f {} "*.gz.$DATAORA_ATTUALI" \; 
find /work/pr-${DOMINIO}-0[0-2]/servers -name "*.stderr*[^gz]" -type f -user bea -mtime +${GGZIP} -exec /usr/bin/gzip -9 -f {} "*.gz.$DATAORA_ATTUALI" \;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This to view your output from find:

```
find ./ -type f -name "nsshow*" -exec echo cp {} /tmp/{}_test \;
cp ./nsshow_SANSW06_FABB /tmp/./nsshow_SANSW06_FABB_test
cp ./nsshow_SANSW02_FABB /tmp/./nsshow_SANSW02_FABB_test
cp ./nsshow_SANSW05_FABA /tmp/./nsshow_SANSW05_FABA_test
cp ./nsshow_SANSW01_FABA /tmp/./nsshow_SANSW01_FABA_test
```

This to run it:
`find ./ -type f -name "nsshow*" -exec cp {} /tmp/{}_test \;`

The above "for" loop is nice and simpel for Advanced work:

```
for f in $(find /work/pr-${DOMINIO}-0[0-2]/servers -name "*.log*[^gz]" -type f -user bea -mtime +${GGZIP})
do
 /usr/bin/gzip -9 -f $f
 mv $f.gz $f.gz.$DATAORA_ATTUALI
done
```

Comment: Can you clarify: a) OS, b) shell, c) is it [gnu find](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html)? d) if so: `find --version`

Comment: d) find (GNU findutils) 4.4.0

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use a simple for loop and do the gzip and rename like this :

```
for f in $(find /work/pr-${DOMINIO}-0[0-2]/servers -name "*.log*[^gz]" -type f -user bea -mtime +${GGZIP}) ; do /usr/bin/gzip -9 -f $f ; mv $f.gz $f.gz.$DATAORA_ATTUALI; done
```